# How to solve the eigenvalues of a complex matrix of very high condition number?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, condition-number

WHAT I FACE: I'm dealing with a complex matrix of very high condition number and I have to solve the eigenvalue and eigenfunction of it. But in Matlab, I got the problem that the results are not converging with increasing resolution number, so these results are not reliable.

WHAT I NEED: I in fact only need to get one eigenvalue and its associated eigenfunction (largest real part), so I tried with eigs in Matlab, but it says that "znaupd did not find any eigenvalues to sufficient accuracy", even though I have relaxed the tolerance to a very high value.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED: As I said, I have tried eig and eigs in Matlab, but these two commands can't give me accurate results.

What should I do if I want to solve this kind of problem (to get one eigenvalue of a very-high-condition-number matrix)? 
Should I move to other solvers other than Matlab? I think Matlab is already the best we can do, right?

Thanks. Any discussion will be appreciated.

By the way, I'm using the collocation spectral method for the grid discretization.

Comment: Is the largest real part eigenvalue also the largest *modulus* eigenvalue, strictly? If so, then power iteration will converge, albeit perhaps very slowly. Either way, if you have an estimate for the desired eigenvalue, then inverse iteration (or a variant; there are many such variants) may be useful.

Comment: No, it's not. It's in fact near to zero. Your suggestion of inverse iteration might work in my case. I am pretty sure that the power iteration method will work in the case of real matrix. But are you sure it will also work for the complex matrix?

Comment: And do you know what's the state of the art of solving the matrix of very high condition number? It's hard to solve this problem accurately.

Comment: The convergence of power or inverse iteration doesn't use anything about real vs. complex, the idea is based entirely on the relationship between matrix norms and eigenvalues.

Comment: As for the state of the art, there is really no such thing. High condition number problems tend to require problem-dependent methods. In particular, in many hard problems arising in applications, the matrix actually has a great deal of prior structure, which enables good preconditioning techniques.

Comment: Thanks lan. How did you trust the results from the eig command in Matlab? I in fact obtained different results when calculating the eigenfunction of a high-condition-number complex matrix using (1) the eig command in Matlab and (2) power method. The eigenvalues are the same from these two methods. I tend to think that the results from the power method is correct since the eig need to do some balance operation to render the matrix tractable for the computation. If the convergence is achieved in power method, the results should be trustable. Is this right?

Comment: You may have to use arbitrary precision floating point numbers and write the matrix code yourself.
The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library : https://gmplib.org/
A C++ wrapper: The GNU MPFR Library : https://www.mpfr.org/
Then use the C++ std::complex template.
This combination works quite well for high precision complex math. I use this often.
I have not found a matrix template that can take this class and provide standard matrix operations.

Comment: I haven't tried Eigen with a high precision complex class? https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html , https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html

Comment: Eigen has a built in complex class that takes a float as a type argument so mpfr might be enough https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ComplexEigenSolver.html#a3604c99a69fac3bee42c88cb2b589143

Comment: Here it is. Eigen with mpfr. I have not tried it. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/structEigen_1_1NumTraits_3_01mpfr_1_1mpreal_01_4.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would work with a complex matrix, but partial pivoting may help out (LU factorization).

`lu(A)`

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html

Comment: The "LU" eigenvalue algorithm is a pretty awful eigenvalue algorithm in most cases, for many reasons including instability.